# How can I make a minimized Jquery library?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that assigns a class to the div that I set automatically after a certain region of the page.

But to run this code, I need to run the jquery 2.2.4 library completely.

scroll - scrollTop - addClass - removeClass

How can I make a minimized library so that I can run these 4 commands?

```
$(function() {
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(this).scrollTop() > 420) {
$('#bar').addClass('bar-sticky');
}else{
$('#bar').removeClass('bar-sticky');
}
});
});
```

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably try writing the code in vanilla javascript

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  if(document.scrollingElement.scrollTop > 420){
    document.getElementById('bar').classList.add('bar-sticky')
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('bar').classList.remove('bar-sticky')
  }
}
```

or use the jquery slim minified version

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can find the other versions here 
https://code.jquery.com/

Comment: Thank you very much, Now, thanks to your vanilla, I don't even need to add a jquery library. I think he uses vanilla in my theme ..


You've made me very happy.